# Add Password Protection to a file editing in vim with read,write and execute premission

Tags: linux, vim

I have test.pl and want this file Password Protected. I used `vim -x filename` then able to password Protected but not able to execute or compile that file. Is there any to executable file

```
vim test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Hello Ram";
```

I got following error:

```
syntax error at text line 1, near "VimCrypt~"
Unrecognized character \x19 at text line 1.
```

Comment: You will need to supply the password to some wrapper that decrypts the script before executing it. So if this is about preventing the user from seeing the source code, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The format used by vim's password protection can only be read by vim, and only with the password. perl can't read it.

You'll need to come up with some other way of implementing the access controls you're after, but without some idea of what your end goal is, we can't really help you.